# Create hyperlinks based on folder content

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create Hyperlinks on a page to certain files within its root folder.

So for instance:

`\Homepage.html` - This will contain the hyperlinks of:

```
\1.html
\2.html
\3.html
etc.
```

I could simply do this manually, but I want to automate the process as the number of files (1,2,3...) will increase.

Can JavaScript do this? If so, how?

Comment: JavaScript alone can't but by using AJAX you could.

Comment: Lots of suggestions here to use AJAX, etc.  Why use JavaScript *at all* for this?  Use PHP to read the directory and write the links as dynamic HTML.  Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the impression you're asking about using JavaScript because you may not know *how* to go about it, at all.  If I'm incorrect then my apologies.  That said...

As others have stated, JS can't do this alone.  You will need a server component (such as PHP) to read the directory to get its files.  From that point you have a lot of options.  My suggestion is, forget JS altogether unless you have some requirement to use it.  Just use DHTML, a basic, fundamental talent of PHP's.  Call this file something like `main.php`:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
// Read directory, spit out links
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            echo '<a href="/'.$entry.'">Link to file '.$entry.'</a><br>';
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The above example taken more or less directly from the [PHP readdir docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php).  Based on your example file names, accessing `main.php` in your browser this should output something like:

```
Link to file 1.html
Link to file 2.html
Link to file 3.html
...
```

You may need to tweak the `href` value to reflect the path to the html file, relative to your root folder.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript cannot do this. You could set up a PHP (or other serverside script) that returns a JSON of the folder contents, since serverside languaged DO have access to that, and then call that script using AJAX.

Comment: Why? Just write the data into a JS variable using PHP and operate on it when the page loads.  AJAX isn't necessary at all here.  In fact, why use JS at all?

Comment: Using an AJAX script will make the code cleaner and more reusable (and it's not very hard at all to do). It will also allow for showing the updates without refreshing the page, if need be.

Comment: No.  Using Ajax is needlessly complex for such a simple problem.  Just because you can doesn't mean you should.  *If* there's a requirement to show updates without loading the page, great, use AJAX. Otherwise you're using a sledgehammer to drive a thumb tack.  And you're introducing a whole mess of complexity at the same time.

Comment: I assumed that there might be such a requirement because otherwise why wouldn't you just do all of it in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

A possible work around:

1. List the folder content from the command line
2. Use the output as input in your browser either copy & paste content in an html input field or some drag & drop method.

To list under Windows (non Unicode):
dir *.exe /B /S /O-G
If you want to save the content to a file
dir *.exe /B /S /O-G > contentList.txt

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript works on client-side, in your browser, what you need is a server-side script such as PHP for example.

JavaScript can't do this!

Answer (score -1):

You'd need to put an HTML element in your page with an ID:

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Then, with JavaScript,

```
for (var i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; i++) {
    document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML += "<a href=\"" + i + ".html\">Link " + i + "</a>";
}
```

The escaped quotation marks (\") are important - messing them up can lead to unexpected results.

**Edit** I read your question carefully and realized you need it to increase as you add more files. In that case, you can either use PHP to generate the JavaScript on the page, i.e.

```
for (var i = 1 ; i <= <?php echo $maxFileIndex; ?> ; i++) {
    document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML += "<a href=\"" + i + ".html\">Link " + i + "</a>";
}
```

or you could do an AJAX request to the server and populate the `div` based on the response.

Comment: And what happens, if there are other files like first_page.html or gears.html? Edit: Just commented, when you edited your answer. xD

Comment: I just went with the example given, that they have numbered pages. If it were me, I'd get a JSON object from the server and iterate over that.

Comment: Thanks guys :) I'll look into PHP and AJAX

Comment: @zeyorama By the way, it is much more helpful to just post an answer that *might* be useful, rather than just "you can't do it".

Comment: Read the first sentence, than the second and you get it ;-)